Dashing Script for Roblox
--Get Normal Tings
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoidRootPart = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local Humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local frontDashAttack = ReplicatedStorage.frha
local frontDashRagdoll = ReplicatedStorage.frha
local frontDashHitbox = ReplicatedStorage.frh
--Initialize Dash Attributes
    --Primary Dashes
Humanoid:SetAttribute("FDSpeed", 0.9)
Humanoid:SetAttribute("BDSpeed", 0.45)
    --Secondary Dashes
Humanoid:SetAttribute("SDSpeed", 0.7)
    --Dash Properties
Humanoid:SetAttribute("DashStrength", 100)
Humanoid:SetAttribute("SDCoolAmount", 3) --Secondary Dash Cooldown Time
Humanoid:SetAttribute("PDCoolAmount", 11) --Primary Dash Cooldown Time
Humanoid:SetAttribute("SDCool", false) --Secondary Dash Cooldown
Humanoid:SetAttribute("PDCool", false) --Primary Dash Cooldown
Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", false)
--Dashing
--Initialize First
local dashStrength = nil
local secondaryDashCoolDownAmount = nil
local primaryDashCoolDownAmount = nil
local inDash = nil
local movingVector = nil
local DashVector = nil
local moving = nil
local stunned = nil
--Forever Initialize Attributes to prevent nil
RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    movingVector = Humanoid:GetAttribute("MovingVector")
    DashVectorVector = Humanoid:GetAttribute("DashVector")
    moving = Humanoid:GetAttribute("Moving")
    stunned = Humanoid:GetAttribute("Stunned")

    dashStrength = Humanoid:GetAttribute("DashStrength")
    secondaryDashCoolDownAmount = Humanoid:GetAttribute("SDCoolAmount")
    primaryDashCoolDownAmount = Humanoid:GetAttribute("PDCoolAmount")
    inDash = Humanoid:GetAttribute("InDash")
end)
local normRate = 0.01

function secondaryDash(duration, strength, rate)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", true)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", true)
    local str = strength
    local minStrength = strength * 0.15
    local tween1 = duration / rate
    local tween2 = str / tween1
    str = strength
    for i = 0, duration, rate do
        timeline = (timeline + rate)
        humanoidRootPart.Velocity = Vector3.new(DashVector.x * str, humanoidRootPart.Velocity.y, DashVector.z * str)
        if str > minStrength then
            str = (str - tween2)
            if str < minStrength then
                str = minStrength
            end
            if str == minStrength or str == 0 then
                break
            end
        end
        task.wait(rate)
    end
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", false)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", false)
end

function frontDash(duration, strength, rate)
    frontDashHitbox:FireServer()
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", true)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", true)
    local touchplr = Humanoid:GetAttribute("TouchedPlr")
    local str = strength
    local minStrength = strength * 0.15
    local tween1 = duration / rate
    local tween2 = str / tween1
    str = strength
    for i = 0, duration, rate do
        touchplr = Humanoid:GetAttribute("TouchedPlr")
        humanoidRootPart.Velocity = Vector3.new(DashVector.x * str, humanoidRootPart.Velocity.y, DashVector.z * str)
        if touchplr ~= false and i * rate >= 0.7 and touchplr ~= nil then
            frontDashAttack:FireServer()
            Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", false)
            Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", false)
            str = 0
            break
        end
        if str > minStrength then
            str = (str - tween2)
            if str < minStrength then
                str = minStrength
            end
            if str == minStrength or str == 0 then
                break
            end
        end
        task.wait(rate)
    end
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", false)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", false)
end

function backDash(duration, strength, rate)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", true)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", true)
    local str = strength
    local minStrength = strength * 0.15
    local tween1 = duration / rate
    local tween2 = str / tween1
    str = strength
    for e = 0, 1 do
        for i = 0, duration, rate do
            humanoidRootPart.Velocity = Vector3.new(DashVector.X * str, humanoidRootPart.Velocity.Y, DashVector.Z * str)
            if str > minStrength then
                str = (str - tween2)
                if str < minStrength then
                    str = minStrength
                end
                if str == minStrength or str == 0 then
                    break
                end
            end
            task.wait(rate)
        end
        task.wait(0.3)
    end
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("Stunned", false)
    Humanoid:SetAttribute("InDash", false)
end

local sDashClock = 0
local pDashClock = 0
local sCool = secondaryDashCoolDownAmount + 1
local pCool = primaryDashCoolDownAmount + 4
local clock = os.clock

function dasherType()
    local direction = Humanoid:GetAttribute("direction")
    if clock() - pDashClock >= pCool then
        if direction == "front" then
            task.spawn(frontDash, 1, 100, 0.01)
        elseif direction == "backwards" then
            task.spawn(backDash, 0.55, 100, 0.01)
        end
        pDashClock = clock()
    end
    if clock() - sDashClock >= sCool then
        if direction == "left" then
            task.spawn(secondaryDash, 0.6, 100, 0.01)
        elseif direction == "right" then
            task.spawn(secondaryDash, 0.6, 100, 0.01)
        end
        sDashClock = clock()
    end
end

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if gameProcessedEvent then return end

    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.ButtonY or input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Q then
        if stunned ~= true and inDash ~= true then
            dasherType()
        end
    end
end)

In this script i tried removing the ${DashVector}'s Y and tried replacing it with the players current Y velocity, because when you dashed it would end up like the Cartoony Ahh fall, but now it just doesn't work at all anymore and just stuns the player forever. I need some insight, did I do something wrong? Any syntax errors? I cant completely debug this since I don't have any third party software to debug this, I don't have Roblox Studio, I code in the Website version of VSCode
